# Autorestart program (script) when reconnecting to ppp0 with sakis3g, UMTSkeeper

Tags: linux, bash, debian, scripting

I have a problem. 
Hardware and software I'm using: Raspberry pi, 3G modem - Huawei e1550, sakis3g and UMTSkeeper to handle connection.
Also I'm using https://github.com/Lora-net/packet_forwarder for my project, it autostarts on boot with a delay of 180 seconds in order for the 3g modem to connect to the network than packet_forwarder send data to my server.
It works fine until the 3g modem loses its connection (2-3 hours after boot it works than reconnect) and the UMTSkeeper regains communication. After this, packet_forwarder stops sending data to the server. It seems to me that packet_forwarder does not know how to monitor the network connection state and if there are any drop, then it does not reconnect itself to the network.
Please help me, how to get it to connect yourself when the network is restored?

Some logs and information:
Here is a *umtskeeper.log* when its reconnect:

```
----
2018-03-13 20:27:32 Testing connection...
2018-03-13 20:27:40 Success... we are online!
2018-03-13 22:11:39 Offline: Network device ppp0 not found or not connected. (n$
2018-03-13 22:11:43 Internet connection is DOWN. Calling Sakis3G connect...
  Sakis3G cmdLine: nice /home/pi/3g/sakis3g connect --sudo --console USBINTERFA$
  Sakis3G says...
  E1550 connected to KYIVSTAR (25503).
  Error: /tmp/sakis3gz.10107.sakis3g: line 3218: warning: command substitution:$

2018-03-13 22:12:11 Testing connection...
2018-03-13 22:12:20 Success... we are online!
```

Here is *ifconfig* for 3g modem iterface:

```
ppp0: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.151.60.124  netmask 255.255.255.255  destination 10.64.64.64
        ppp  txqueuelen 3  (Point-to-Point Protocol)
        RX packets 106  bytes 7905 (7.7 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 108  bytes 7617 (7.4 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Here is *tcpdump -AUq port 3000* for port who sends data to server (and when 3g modem disconnects, ppp0 interface disappears from the ifconfig list):

```
listening on ppp0, link-type LINUX_SLL (Linux cooked), capture size 262144 bytes
-----
-----
tcpdump: pcap_loop: The interface went down
3124 packets captured
3124 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
```

Here is autostart script for packet_forwarder:

```
#!/bin/bash
sleep 180
sleep 10
gpio mode 7 out
gpio write 7 1
sleep 0.5
gpio write 7 0
sleep 0.5
cd packet_forwarder/lora_pkt_fwd/
./lora_pkt_fwd
exit 0
```

Answer (score 0):

As you said, if the `packet_forwarder` fails to monitor the ppp link state himself, you will probably have to do it for him.

A good place to check the state and restart the `packet_forwarder` would be in `/etc/ppp/ip-up.d/`.
You can put a shell script in there that will be executed when the ppp link is established.

See the content of `/etc/ppp/ip-up` for more details.